# General nested for-loop for N x d matrix in Julia

Tags: for-loop, julia, nested-loops

I would like to write a function in Julia that takes in a `N x d` numeric matrix where `N` is number of data points and `d` is the number of parameters:

1. Extract the min and max along each dimension (this I can do)
2. User-specified level of discretization (e.g. 1.0 in the below example)
3. Returns a matrix `M x d` which contains all combinations (see description of `M` below).

As a simple example with `d = 5`, I have taken the results of part 1 where I obtain the min and max along each dimension.

```
minX = [ -1.0  -0.5  -1.1  -1.0  -0.9]
maxX = [3.8  2.5  1.8  3.1  2.3]
test=[minX[i]:1.0:maxX[i] for i in 1:5]
```

(I have purposely taken a coarse step of size 1.0). My question is how can I loop through test in a systematic way (without making 5 for loops) such that I get all combinations that result from the discretization which would yield a matrix of size `M x d` where

```
M = prod([length(x) for x in test]) # 1200 in this example.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a "hidden" function [`Iterators.product`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.product) that iterates the cartesian product set.

```
R = Iterators.product(test...)
size(R) # (5, 4, 3, 5, 4)
```

All you need is then concatenating the elements in `R` vertically. It can be a single loop over `R` to fill a pre-allocated array, or more concisely

```
[map(transpose ∘ collect, R)...;] # 1200 * 5 matrix
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!